# Javascript object show in blank

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I faced a problem when i console my object it shows blank but mean time when i expand the object it shows correct value, and from my controller end i cannot catch the value What's the problem?

[image]

that means.

```
console.log(object.limit)
-->undefined
```

Comment: Can we see more of the controller? Where does the object.limit come from?

Comment: Certainly an `async` call

Comment: can you add the code where you console.log the object itself?

Comment: Objects are passed by reference to console. When you `console.log` it, at that moment it's empty, only later are those two properties added.

Answer (score 0):

> I have faced a similar problem multiple times, majorly it's due to a
>   sync behavior of the variable, so at time you are checking the
>   variable might not have that value, sometimes it's not a JavaScript
>   Object, or sometimes there is a very silly mistake as `.limit` instead
>   of `.limit` .

Some tips for debugging

- Check output of `Object.keys(objectVariable)`.
- I hate this, but try doing `alert(objectVariable)` as it will print the value at that time of execution, where console.log prints latest variable value regardless of when printed.
- Try printing `JSON.stringify(objectVariable)`, same as alert but in console, also prints value at time of execution not latest.

Comment: Means that variable is not having any array elements aka assigned any value at time of checking `.limit`. For further debugging we will need implementation code, create a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net) if possible or share controller code.

Comment: Cool. Glad if it helped.

Answer (score 0):

Try to define one varible in console
var object =  { limit:"1",skip:'2'};

console.log(object.limit);

Answer (score 0):

- As per the [jkondratowicz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/752495/jkondratowicz) comment, Objects are passed by reference to console. When you console.log it, at that moment it's empty, only later are those two properties added.
- properties are added inside object depending on JavaScript implementation.

Hence, When you are trying to do `console.log(object.limit)` that time your object is an empty object but after some lines of code you are adding the properties(`limit`) into the `object` and then it is available into the object.